# Justification for softmax and sigmoid functions in classification models

Tags: logistic, classification, softmax

In multi-class classification problems, we often build a model that first computes some score $s_i=f(X_i;\theta)$ for each class of instance $i$, where $\theta$ are parameters of the model. Then, we use the softmax function $p(y|X) = \frac{e^s_i}{\sum_j e^s_j}$ to convert them to probabilities. To train such models, we find the parameters $\theta$ that maximizes the log likelihood $\sum_i^m \ln p(y_i|X_i)$ on a training set $\{(X_1, y_1), \dots, (X_m, y_m)\}$. This is equivalent to minimizing the cross-entropy loss. Similarly, in the two-class classification case, we often use the sigmoid function to convert scores to probabilities.

My question is what justifies the use of softmax or sigmoid. Many other functions can also convert scores to probabilities. Is there any specific reason that they are more optimal?

Note: Here are some examples of $f(X;\theta)$: it can take the form of linear function $f(X)=\theta^T X$ or be a neural net or really a lot other models.

Comment: What kinds of alternatives are you thinking about? It's hard to say why something is "more optimal" when there's no alternative to compare softmax/sigmoid to.

Comment: For the sigmoid, any S-shaped continuous function such as `tanh` with appropriate scaling will do, right?   Some people say that there are some justifications to use softmax and sigmoid if we use maximum likelihood, but I cannot find a reasonable source with proofs. Also, these two seem everyone's choices. So I am curious why and why no alternative is considered.

Comment: `tanh` is equivalent to a scaled logistic function, so it's not really an alternative. The cumulative density function (CDF) of any unbounded continuous variable would also work; the normal CDF leads to probit regression (including multinomial), which is very often used in some fields, and the Cauchy CDF lead to Cauchit regression (rarely used but available in R). The optimal one depends on unobserved qualities of the data.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Comment: @Noah I think this is a good start on an answer!